# Colormap is not categorizing the data properly

Tags: matplotlib, plot, ipython, colorbar

Here is my script to plot data from a Geogtiff file using basemap. The data is categorical and there are 13 categories within this domain. The problem is that some categories get bunched up into one colour and thus some resolution is lost.
Unfortunately, I do not know how to fix this. I read that `plt.cm.get_cmp` is better for discrete datasets but I have not gotten it to work unfortunately.

```
gtif = 'some_dir'

ds = gdal.Open(gtif)
data = ds.ReadAsArray()
gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()
proj = ds.GetProjection()
xres = gt[1]
yres = gt[5]

xmin = gt[0] + xres
xmax = gt[0] + (xres * ds.RasterXSize) - xres
ymin = gt[3] + (yres * ds.RasterYSize) + yres
ymax = gt[3] - yres
xy_source = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax+xres:xres, ymax+yres:ymin:yres]
ds = None

fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=[12, 11])
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
ax2.set_title("Land use plot")
bm2 = Basemap(ax=ax2,projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=ymin,urcrnrlat=ymax,llcrnrlon=xmin,urcrnrlon=xmax,resolution='l')
bm2.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.2)
bm2.drawcountries(linewidth=0.2)

data_new=np.copy(data)
data_new[data_new==255] = 0

nbins = np.unique(data_new).size
cb =plt.cm.get_cmap('jet', nbins+1)
img2 =bm2.imshow(np.flipud(data_new), cmap=cb)
ax2.set_xlim(3, 6)
ax2.set_ylim(50,53)
plt.show()

labels = [str(i) for i in np.unique(data_new)]
cb2=bm2.colorbar(img2, "right", size="5%", pad='3%', label='NOAH Land Use Category')
cb2.set_ticklabels(labels)
cb2.set_ticks(np.unique(data_new))
```

Here are the categories that are found within the domain (numbered classes):

```
np.unique(data_new)

array([ 0,  1,  4,  5,  7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17], dtype=uint8)
```

Thanks so much for any help here. <strike>I have also attached the output image that shows the mismatch.</strike>  (not working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this colormap problem is independent of the use of basemap. The following is therefore applicable to any matplotlib plot.

The problem here is that creating a colormap from `n` values distributes those values equally over the colormap range. Some values from the image therefore fall into the same colorrange within the colormap.

To prevent this, one can generate a colormap with the initial number of categories as shown below.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors

# generate some data
data = np.array( [ 0,  1,  4,  5,  7, 10]*8 )
np.random.shuffle(data)
data = data.reshape((8,6))

# generate colormap and norm
unique = np.unique(data)
vals = np.arange(int(unique.max()+1))/float(unique.max())
cols = plt.cm.jet(vals)
cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(cols, int(unique.max())+1)
norm=matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=-0.5, vmax=unique.max()+0.5)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
im = ax.imshow(data, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
for i  in range(data.shape[0]):
    for j in range(data.shape[1]):
        ax.text(j,i,data[i,j], color="w", ha="center", va="center")

cb = fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax,  norm=norm)
cb.set_ticks(unique)

plt.show()
```

---

This can be extended to exclude the colors not present in the image as follows:

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors

# generate some data
data = np.array( [ 0,  1,  4,  5,  7, 10]*8 )
np.random.shuffle(data)
data = data.reshape((8,6))

unique, newdata = np.unique(data, return_inverse=1)
newdata = newdata.reshape(data.shape)

# generate colormap and norm
new_unique = np.unique(newdata)
vals = np.arange(int(new_unique.max()+1))/float(new_unique.max())
cols = plt.cm.jet(vals)
cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(cols, int(new_unique.max())+1)
norm=matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=-0.5, vmax=new_unique.max()+0.5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
im = ax.imshow(newdata, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
for i  in range(newdata.shape[0]):
    for j in range(newdata.shape[1]):
        ax.text(j,i,data[i,j], color="w", ha="center", va="center")

cb = fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax,  norm=norm)
cb.ax.set_yticklabels(unique)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I tried but I am not sure I can with my reputation level. Or perhaps it is the mobile version

Comment: Perhaps as a final comment, is there no way to alter the last for loop? I am still experiencing issues with speed.

Comment: By "the last for-loop" you mean the for-loops that set the numbers on the canvas? That one I only introduced for demonstration purposes as to see which value is on which pixel. I didn't think you would actually use it in a real world scenario, especially because when there is much more data, the pixels become much smaller and hence the numbers become unreadable anyways. But the short answer is "no", you need as many matplotlib.texts as there are pixels. What makes this slow is not the for-loop but the fact that you add many many text labels.